# MvxImageViewLoader and plugin

Tags: plugins, xamarin, mvvmcross

I was having trouble getting the MvxImageViewLoader to work when I came across this post:

[MvxImageViewLoader binding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273886/mvximageviewloader-binding-not-working)

Which after reading and going back to the N+2 tutorial, I realized that I'd missed adding the File and DownloadCache plugins (this is why video tutorials are such a pain, impossible to skim). So I installed them via nuget, but now when I try and start my application, before the first view even loads, I get this exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxRegistryFillerExtensions.Fill'.
```

Any idea what I've missed now?

Comment: If you find video tutorials such a pain, then I'd 100% welcome your offer to convert them into a less painful format. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all your nuget packages are from the same version.

MissingMethodException is most likely caused by having different versions in the same project.

Comment: I'm using the Nuget packages and they claim they are all up-to-date.

Comment: I just reinstalled all the Nuget packages and now it seems to be behaving itself. I think something got screwy with visual studio tracking the packages. Thanks for your help.